# How to use Azure DataBricks Api to submit job?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows, gcp-databricks

I am a beginner in Azure Databricks and I want to use APIs to create cluster and submit job in python. I am stuck as I am unable to do so. Also if I have an existing cluster how will the code look like? I got job id after running this code but unable to see any output.

```
import requests

DOMAIN = ''
TOKEN = ''
response = requests.post(
  'https://%s/api/2.0/jobs/create' % (DOMAIN),
  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN},
  json={
       "name": "SparkPi spark-submit job",
       "new_cluster": {
       "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
       "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
       "num_workers": 2
       },
       "spark_submit_task": {
       "parameters": [
           "--class",
            "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
            "dbfs:/FileStore/sparkpi_assembly_0_1.jar",
            "10"
            ]
        }
    }
)
if response.status_code == 200:
  print(response.json())
else:
  print("Error launching cluster: %s: %s" % (response.json()["error_code"], response.json()["message"]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Jobs at Databricks could be executed two ways (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#create)):

- on a new cluster - that's how you do it right now
- on existing cluster - remove the `new_cluster` block, and add the `existing_cluster_id` field with the ID of existing cluster.  If you don't have a cluster yet, then you can create it via [Cluster API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#create)

When you create a job, then you get back the job ID that could be used to edit the job or delete it.  You can also launch the job using the [Run Now API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now).  But if you just want to execute the job without create the Job in the UI, then you need to look onto [Run Submit API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit). Either of the APIs will return the ID of specific job run, and then you can use [Run Get API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-get) to get status of the job, or [Run Get Output API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-get-output) to get the results of execution.

Comment: I am unable to get the output of value of pi, though I am able to see it in logs, can you help me with that if I want to print the value of Pi?

Comment: you need to use "Run Get Output API" to get it

Comment: in my pipeline, I would like to wait until job is completed and then move to next task , how it can be done ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73291921/wait-until-databrick-job-is-completed-in-devops-pipeline