# Wait until databrick job is completed in Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a pipeline in DevOps, where I trigger databrick job via [databricks jobs run-now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli#:%7E:text=output%20is%20displayed.-,Run%20a%20job,-To%20display%20usage) command

```
databricks jobs run-now --job-id 246
```

output

```
{
  "run_id": 1010,
  "number_in_job": 101022 
}
```

As the job is triggered, the agent start executing the next task in the pipeline, and databrick job is not completed yet, here I would like to wait until the databricks job is completed in databricks and move to the next task

Comment: you may try `dbx` tool that has `--trace` command-line parameter: https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-dbx-launch-trace

Comment: "Job shall be deployed prior to be launched." , apparently to use `launch` command that has `--trace` parameter it need to be deployed first and that is something beyond my scope

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to wait for the job to complete using job run ID:

> ```
> while True:
>     status = jobs_service.get_run(run_id)
>     print(status)
>     result_state = status["state"].get("result_state", None)
>     if result_state:
>         print(result_state)
>         assert result_state == "SUCCESS"    break
>     else:
>         time.sleep(5)
> ```

Thanks to `@Michael Shtelma` and `@Piotr Majer` for their contribution in [Implementing CI/CD on Databricks Using Databricks Notebooks and Azure DevOps](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/09/20/part-1-implementing-ci-cd-on-databricks-using-databricks-notebooks-and-azure-devops.html).

Answer (score 1):

I do the same in my devops pipeline. I use powershell and use the rest api for databricks . As you can see below, I use the same "run now" rest endpoint to trigger the job and then use "runs get" endpoint to get the status, and wait until it is "running" or "pending".

So, you can use this to both trigger the job and then wait for it to finish.

```
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $bearertoken,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $jobid,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $azureregion
)

$auth= @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $bearertoken" }
$jobrunurl="https://$azureregion.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now"
$jobmonitorrunurl="https://$azureregion.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get"


$payload='{"job_id":' + $jobid + '}'

Write-Host $payload



$resp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jobrunurl -Headers $auth -Method Post -Body $payload -ContentType 'application/json' 

$runid=$resp.run_id

$monitorrunresp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jobmonitorrunurl -Headers $auth -Method Get -Body @{'run_id'= $runid} 
$status=""

do
{
    if ($status -ne "")
    {
       Write-Host "Waiting for the job run to finish.Sleeping for 15 seconds"
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    }


    $status= $monitorrunresp.state.life_cycle_state
    $monitorrunresp=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jobmonitorrunurl -Headers $auth -Method Get -Body @{'run_id'= $runid} 

}while ($status -eq "RUNNING" -or $status -eq "PENDING")

$resultstate = $monitorrunresp.state.result_state

if ($resultstate -ne "SUCCESS")
{
    Write-Host "Job $jobid failed"
}

else
{
    Write-Host "Job $jobid succeeded"
}
```

You can name this script

```
Run-Databricksjob.ps1
```

and then call from your devops pipeline by using a powershell task and then providing the location of the script and the arguments like

```
-bearertoken $(BearerToken) -jobid "yourjobid" -azureregion "yourazureregion"
```